# Pandas combine two different length of time series dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to combine two different timeframes of pandas dataframe. The first dataframe has 1 hour timeseries. and the second dataframe has 1 minute timeseries.

```
1 hour dataframe
     get_time   value
0  1599739200  123.10
1  1599742800  136.24
2  1599750000  224.14

1 minute dataframe
       get_time  value
0   1599739200   2.11
1   1599739260   3.11
2   1599739320   3.12
3   1599742800   4.23
4   1599742860   2.22
5   1599742920   1.11
6   1599746400   7.24
7   1599746460  22.10
8   1599746520   2.13
9   1599750000   5.14
10  1599750060  12.10
11  1599750120  21.30
```

I want to combine those two dataframes, so the value of 1 hour dataframe will be mapped in 1 minute dataframe. if there is no 1 hour value then the mapped value will be nan.

```
Desired Result:
     get_time    value         1h mapped value
0   1599739200   2.11                  123.10
1   1599739260   3.11                  123.10
2   1599739320   3.12                  123.10
3   1599742800   4.23                  136.24
4   1599742860   2.22                  136.24
5   1599742920   1.11                  136.24
6   1599746400   7.24                     NaN
7   1599746460  22.10                     NaN
8   1599746520   2.13                     NaN
9   1599750000   5.14                  224.14
10  1599750060  12.10                  224.14
11  1599750120  21.30                  224.14
```

Basically i want to combine those dataframe with these logic:

```
if (1m_get_time >= 1h_get_time) and (1m_get_time < 1h_get_time+60minutes)
   1h mapped value = 1h value
else:
    1h mapped value = nan
```

Currently i use recursive method. But it takes long time for big size of data. here is the example of dataframe:

```
dfhigh_ = pd.DataFrame({
    'get_time' : [1599739200, 1599742800, 1599750000],
    'value' : [123.1, 136.24, 224.14],
})

dflow_ = pd.DataFrame({
    'get_time' : [1599739200, 1599739260, 1599739320, 1599742800, 1599742860, 1599742920, 1599746400, 1599746460, 1599746520, 1599750000, 1599750060, 1599750120],
    'value' : [2.11, 3.11, 3.12, 4.23, 2.22, 1.11, 7.24, 22.1, 2.13, 5.14, 12.1, 21.3],
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floor the `get_time` from `dflow_` to nearest hour representation then use `Series.map` to map the values from `dfhigh_` to `dflow_` based on this rounded timestamp:

```
hr = dflow_['get_time'] // 3600 * 3600
dflow_['mapped_value'] = hr.map(dfhigh_.set_index('get_time')['value'])
```

---

```
      get_time  value  mapped_value
0   1599739200   2.11        123.10
1   1599739260   3.11        123.10
2   1599739320   3.12        123.10
3   1599742800   4.23        136.24
4   1599742860   2.22        136.24
5   1599742920   1.11        136.24
6   1599746400   7.24           NaN
7   1599746460  22.10           NaN
8   1599746520   2.13           NaN
9   1599750000   5.14        224.14
10  1599750060  12.10        224.14
11  1599750120  21.30        224.14
```

Comment: Does the 3600 * 3600 flooring to hour method work on any timestamp?

Comment: @SebastianPeterlin No it does not... its specifically applicable for this example where unix timestamps are specified in seconds.

Comment: Ok @ShubhamSharma thank you, so would it be more applicable to do something like this with dt.hour:
from datetime import datetime
hr = pd.Series([datetime.fromtimestamp(x) for x in dflow_['get_time']]).dt.hour
dfhigh_['get_time'] = pd.Series([datetime.fromtimestamp(x) for x in dfhigh_['get_time']]).dt.hour 
dflow_['mapped_value'] = hr.map(dfhigh_.set_index('get_time')['value'])
or to check if unix timestamps are specified in seconds?

Comment: @SebastianPeterlin Alternatively you can do `hr = pd.to_datetime(df['get_time'], unit='s').dt.floor('h')` :)

Comment: Yes I was going to use pd.to_datetime() but I thought it was giving me an incorrect datetime, however it seems that pd.to_datetime() defaults to UTC timezone whereas datetime.fromtimestamp() defaults to local timezone. Didn't know about dt.floor (thanks) either but I don't thing dt.floor is necessary when you can use dt.hour.

Comment: @SebastianPeterlin `floor` is actually necessary here as `dt.hour` only returns the hour component of the timestamp without the actual date..

Comment: Correct @ShubhamSharma, I was narrow sighted and was only looking at the current dataset where all data occurred on the same day

Answer (score 1):

This should work (for edge cases as well):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

dfhigh_ = dfhigh_.rename(columns={'value': '1h mapped value'})
df_new = pd.merge(dflow_, dfhigh_, how='outer', on=['get_time'])
df_new.get_time = [datetime.fromtimestamp(x) for x in df_new['get_time']]

for idx,row in df_new.iterrows():
    if not np.isnan(row['1h mapped value']):
        current_hour, current_1h_mapped_value = row['get_time'].hour, row['1h mapped value']
        for sub_idx,sub_row in df_new.loc[(df_new.get_time.dt.hour == current_hour) & np.isnan(df_new['1h mapped value'])].iterrows():
            df_new.loc[sub_idx, '1h mapped value'] = current_1h_mapped_value
```

Comment: thanks, this also work. Although still use recursive method, but faster than i made before.